# Item Number Generation Table - Excel

Tags: excel

Not sure how to ask this, however I require a drop-down list or table? which can generate a unique item id for my products. To eliminate the need for me to type the information in each time. Below shows the information I require.

[image: Requirements]
With the information above this will be generated as demonstrated below,

[image: Outcome]

Comment: Can you add the formula(s) you've tried to the question.

Comment: @Carol I do not have any formulas, not sure how to start or what it is I need - SC

Comment: This site expects you to have had a go but I can point you in the right direction. Your date component - which date are you representing? If you're representing TODAY (the day you enter the information) then you'll have to use VBA or the date will constantly change. If you're getting the date from another column, then which column? Will there ever be more than 26 rows per day? i.e. will you use A - Z then need to start from AA, AB etc.

Comment: Ideally id like to select the date as I may not access the document the day I purchase goods. And yes there will not be more than 26 goods per day

Answer (score 0):

This assumes your reference is in column A, your description is in column B, and your Purchase Date is in column C. What it won't do is check to see if that part already has a reference and re-use that reference if it does. You can adapt the formula using INDEX/MATCH to check for that if it's needed.

```
=IF(B2<>"","SC" & TEXT(C2,"dd") & TEXT(C2,"mm") & IF(TEXT(C2,"dd") & TEXT(C2,"mm")=MID(A1,3,4),CHAR(CODE(RIGHT(A1,1))+1),"A"),"")
```